# levenshteinSim in R utilizando dois dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Dataframe:

```
dataNomeAlunos

    NomeAluno                 Nota Materia
    Marcos Souza Magalhaes     10  Port
    Junior Moraes               5  Mat
    Mirela Chavier              3  Port

dataNomeMatch

   NomeAluno                 Nota Materia
   Marcos Sousa Magalhaes     10  Portugues
   Jr Moraes                   5  Matematica
```

Estou com uma duvida em relação ao funcionamento da função `levenshteinSim`, pacote `RecordLinkage`.
Tenho dois dataframes, `dataNomeAlunos` e `dataNomeMatch`, como ele reage quando as colunas tem a quantidade de informações diferente?

E como eu poderia utilizar o retorno dele para identificar o "Match" ?

**Dados.**

```
dataNomeAlunos <- read.table(text = "
NomeAluno                  Nota  Materia
'Marcos Souza Magalhaes'     10  Port
'Junior Moraes'               5  Mat
'Mirela Chavier'              3  Port
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dataNomeMatch <- read.table(text = "
NomeAluno                  Nota  Materia
'Marcos Sousa Magalhaes'     10  Portugues
'Jr Moraes'                   5  Matematica
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```